# Working with single XML definitions as if it was multiple

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

It is hard to explain, let me give a shot: I have this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <test>
        <a>
            <b>Lorem 1</b>
        </a>
        <a>
            <b>Lorem 2</b>
            <b>Lorem 3</b>
            <b>Lorem 4</b>
        </a>
    </test>
```

And I am converting it into an Object like this with PHP:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($obj) ;
```

It produces this Object output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [b] => Lorem 1
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Lorem 2
                            [1] => Lorem 3
                            [2] => Lorem 4
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**"Lorem 1" is assigned to "b" directly**, but others converted into an array...

Now, how to make "Lorem 1" like others??

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Lorem 1 // like this!!

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Lorem 2
                            [1] => Lorem 3
                            [2] => Lorem 4
```

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: Yep, that's a bug alright! I had this a while back. Was using a SoapClient and the fix was to use `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` as a constructor flag. Too bad they didn't implement a similar flag for xml parsing...

Comment: is there any equaliviant of SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS in XML operations in PHP? @AlexTartan

Comment: From what I could find, no. Your best shot is to make a method that parses it and converts nodes to arrays based on some logic.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @AlexTartan